# How to send json object to html page in webapp2?

Tags: python, json, webapp2

I am getting all the data from database through query and converting into JSON object. This JSON object data need to show on html page table.

How can I send the JSON object to html page in using webapp2 framework?

For example :

```
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'   
        obj = {
        'success': 'some var', 
        'payload': 'some var'
              }
```

`self.response.out.write(obj)`  i.e the json object need to send to an html page to show case the output.

Comment: You can either fetch the json with ajax on front-end to render with, say, Handlebars.js/Mustache.js/whatever or render the template on back-end by passing the json to your jinja2(or whatever you're using) template. You'll need to show what you've tried & what specific issue you've run into to get more help.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information you provided, there are two ways for you to do this.

1) Use a JavaScript (or a JS library, such as jQuery) from your webpage to fetch the JSON object from your server. This option most closely matches your question, since you are using the `application/json` value for your `content-type` response header. However, you will also need to serialize the Python dictionary to a JSON-compatible string using the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) like so:

```
self.response.out.write(json.dumps(obj))
```

2) Render the JSON object into your webpage as a variable that can be read by JavaScript. This is the least compatible with the code you provided, since you would still be rendering an HTML page, but part of it would include a JSON-compatible string. It might look something like the following:

```
self.response.headers['content-type'] = 'text/html'

response_body = """
<html>
<script>(function() {
  yourJsonParseFn("%s");
}())</script>
</html>
""" % json.dumps(obj)

self.response.out.write(response_body)
```

Either way, you would end up providing the JSON object to your webpage for JavaScript to handle.

Comment: Awesome! Don't forget to mark this answer as correct so that others can reference it.